# Java - GUI (swing) - Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, nullpointerexception

I got 2 classes:
- 1st. makes a frame (JFrame) and adds a panel (JPanel) on it
- second one makes the panel and draws a rectangle on it (at least i thought it would)

this is the first class

```
class Frame {
JFrame frame;
Panel panel;

void draw() {
    frame = new JFrame ("qwertz");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(300,200);

    panel = new Panel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.paint();
    frame.add(panel);
    }}
```

and the second

```
class Panel extends JPanel {
void paint() {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();

    g.drawRect(50,50,90,70);
}}
```

when i call the draw() method from the first class it throws this exception at me:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException  
          at Panel.paint(Panel.java:8) ((  g.drawRect(50,50,90,70);  ))
          at Frame.draw(Frame.java:15) ((  panel.paint();            ))
```

Comment: Panel is reserved Java name for awt.Panel, change that to MyPanel

Comment: Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you're supposed to paint. To paint a component, override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of the `JPanel` then call `repaint();`

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override // <-- this makes a compiler error if you typod the method name
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(50,50,90,70);
    }
}
```

and

```
panel = new MyPanel();
panel.setLayout(null);
panel.repaint(); // <<---- Look here! It says repaint() not paint()
frame.add(panel);
```

Also, if all you have to do is paint on this panel, I'd consider using a plain-old `Component`, and overriding `paint(Graphics g)` instead of `paintComponent(Graphics g)`. `paintComponent(Graphics g)` is exclusively for swing components.

Comment: what exactly happens, when you override the **paintComponent(Graphics g)** method and don't add  **super.paintComponent(Graphics g)** to the first line of the method implementation ?

Comment: It won't do any of the other painting that the class would normally do, had you not overwritten that method, such as painting childred added to a container.

Answer (score 1):

instead of implementing the paint method, you should implement the paintComponent(Graphics g) method. This way, the graphics object you have is valid.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to draw the panel before it is added to the Frame. Try to move `frame.paint();` below `frame.add(panel);`. Additionally if you are using Swing you should use JPanel instead of Panel.